# How do you know if a CA is trusted?

Tags: code-signing, trust, certificate-authority

I have a client who wants their app code signed, so we pointed them to a few well known, well trusted CAs (Verisign, Thawt, etc), then they came back with InstantSSL (because it was only 180/yr as opposed to 500/yr).

How do I know that InstantSSL will be trusted on a customer of this application's computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstantSSL certificates has Comodo as the root authority. It is installed and trusted by default on all recent Windows versions. (And it is [on the current list](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/f/14f7067b-69d3-473a-ba5e-70d04aea5929/windows%20root%20certificate%20program%20members%20november%202009.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia to the rescue !](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers) :-)

Comment: Ignore my post, I didn't notice that it's about Windows code-signing.

Comment: You can always delete bad answers you make.  That means only people with 10K+ rep can see your mistakes.